# how to get the information of objects loaded into memory

Tags: visualvm, jvisualvm, java

In my project we are using a small profiling tool for Java. It shows all objects loaded into memory by our application and reflects changes in the objects in real-time. We mostly use it for debugging.

My question is: How can it work? How does an external application know what my app has loaded into memory? Is there some kind of API available for it?

Answer (score 3):

There are several options available.

1. Make a heap dump and just analyze that.
2. Use the Instrumentation API. Note, this is a *very* advanced topic and most Java developers don't even have a clue about its existence, nor have any practical use for it as is (though the tools made possible are widely used).

Answer (score -1):

You can use java visualVM to see the objects loaded in to memory.

Comment: How does this answer the OPs question?